# Bind SelectIndexChanged event from parent control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom UserControl (ConditionPanel), which contains multiple other custom usercontrols of type ConditionControl. These ConditionControls are added dynamically at runtime. I have a dropdownlist inside each conditioncontrol and, when I add a condition control at runtime I want to bind it's SelectedIndexChanged event.

I'm keeping information about all the custom controls already added in a session variable so I can add them again after each postback.

The problem is that when i change the index of my dropdownlist, the postback of the whole page occurs first and the control that triggered it won't exist anymore since another will be created in it's place in the postback. And so my IndexChangedEvent doesn't trigger ever this way. I tried binding it in the OnInit event but that too does not work.

```
FieldDD.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(FieldDD_SelectedIndexChanged1);
```

Any idea how I can make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with objects added at runtime is if you don't assign an ID by your own the will get automatic IDs on a post back. By setting the ID's you can ensure the events will be called correctly.

Comment: I am setting a different ID for each ConditionControl and each ConditionPanel. But inside my ConditionControl the DropDownList is created statically. If I create it dynamically will it solve my problem ?

Comment: give it a try. Important is that you ensure on post back that you recreate all your dynamic controls with the SAME ID.

http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/09/maintain-dynamic-control-events-data-during-postback.html